# Passing the site title to the application template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm building my first Ember application but somehow I can't get it to work properly.

In my site templates are rendered in an outlet of the application template. Then there are some routes to different sites. Each site has a different title. The application template has a placeholder for this title.

But how to display a specific title that is related to the underlying site controller (index, about, ...)?

I found this here: [Setting page title with ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588523/setting-page-title-with-ember-js) but it doesn't fit for me. Is there a proper way doing this? Or do I really have to give my h1 tag an id and set it with jQuery?

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1912/edit

Comment: This should make things easy but Im not sure if this is available yet. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the title property of the context of your template. 
For the application template, this is the `App.ApplicationController`.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('application').set('title', "Home");
  }
});
```

To set the document title as well, you canjust add an observer to fire whenever the title is changed.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  titleDidChange: Ember.observer(function(){
    document.title = this.get('title');
  }, 'title')
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1921/edit

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the title in all routes, you can reopen the `Ember.Route` class:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  activate: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    var title = this.get('title') || '';
    document.title = title;
  }
});
```

So defining a title property in your route, will make the `document.title` change when transitioned to that route.

For example:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  title: 'index' // changes the title to index
});

App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  title: 'foo'  // changes the title to foo
});

App.BarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  title: 'bar'  // changes the title to bar
});

App.NotitleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({}); // don't change the title
```

**Observation:** this implemantation isn't binding aware

Please give a look. The source code http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1918/edit. The embedded demo http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1918