# How can I definitively change the title of my Ember application?

Tags: ember.js

I know this question is similar to [Setting page title with ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588523/setting-page-title-with-ember-js) (among others), but what I'd like to know is if there's a better way to change the title tag of the page permanently, so that when I navigate to the page there is not a delay between loading and setting the page title.

Currently, I am simply setting the title to my page in the application route like so:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    Ember.$(document).attr('title', "My Application");
  }
});
```

Which works great but has a significant delay between showing "MyApplication" and "My Application."

It would be great if I could set the title earlier in the pipline somewhere to eliminate this delay.

Thanks!

Comment: I are you trying to change the title dynamically for each route? Or generally for the entire app?

Comment: Ah, I'm new to Ember and didn't realize there was an index.html...doh!  I will be changing them dynamically for each route, so I guess I'll stick with the way I'm doing it and update index.html with what I want the entire app to have.  Hope that makes sense but thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try modifying the title attribute directly in the index.html
`app/index.html`

Change:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My Application</title> <!-- here -->
```

Comment: Aren't I a dummy :).  Thanks Juan.