# How to move the head tag to a partial in EmberJS with EmberCLI

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently working with an EmberJS application and I'm wondering how to make an the `<head>` a partial. I've tried adding `{{render 'shared/head'}}` but it doesn't get compiled by Ember.

What I currently have right now:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>EmberApp</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  {{content-for 'head'}}

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/whole-new-home.css">

  {{content-for 'head-footer'}}
</head>
```

What I'm hoping to achieve:

```
<!-- app/index.html -->
...
<head>
  {{render 'shared/head'}}

  {{content-for 'head'}}

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/whole-new-home.css">

  {{content-for 'head-footer'}}
</head>
...

<!-- app/templates/shared/_head.hbs -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>{{appName}}</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{{render 'shared/head'}}`, try `{{partial 'shared/head'}}`.

I assume you're seeing something like "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You used `{{render 'shared.head'}}`, but 'shared.head' can not be found as either a template or a view."? Also note that if you're using Ember CLI, the standard is to prefix partials with a `-` instead of an `_`.

Comment: What I'm getting is actually static text. The `{{render 'shared/head'}}` isn't being parsed.

Comment: Ah, right - you can't do that from `index.html`. The `content-for` hooks are exclusively for addons. If your goal is to have a dynamic `title`, [there are a variety of approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588523/setting-page-title-with-ember-js).